# instead using die in error

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i'm currently making a registration page. It includes hashing of password and validation. When I use "die" it stops the form and displays the error. I want to display the error on the same page.

```
<?php 

// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
require("common.php"); 

$ErrorTest ="";
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{ 
    // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty username 
    if(empty($_POST['username'])) 
    {
        $ErrorTest = "Please enter a username.";
    }       

    if(empty($_POST['password'])) 
    {
        $ErrorTest = "Please enter a password."; 
    }

    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    {
         $ErrorTest = "Invalid E-Mail Address";
    }   

    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            1 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
    "; 


    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        $ErrorTest = "Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage(); 
    } 
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

    if($row) 
    {
        $ErrorTest = "This email address is already registered";
    } 

    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            1 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            email = :email 
    "; 

    $query_params = array( 
        ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        $ErrorTest ="Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage(); 
    } 

    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

    if($row) 
    { 
        $ErrorTest =  "This username is already in use"; 
    } 

    $query = " 
        INSERT INTO users ( 
            username, 
            password, 
            salt, 
            email 
        ) VALUES ( 
            :username, 
            :password, 
            :salt, 
            :email 
        ) 
    "; 
    $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 


    $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 

    { 
        $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
    } 

    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'], 
        ':password' => $password, 
        ':salt' => $salt, 
        ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    {  
        $ErrorTest = "Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage(); 
    } 

    // This redirects the user back to the login page after they register 
    header("Location: myprofile.php"); 
    $ErrorTest = "Redirecting to admin_login.php"; 
}
```

?>

the `die ("please enter a username")` I want to display it on the same page. I tried also to put it on a javascript but when I put wrong infomation on one textboxes, it pop-ups all the error and displays the query.

Answer (score 2):

The way I'd go about it is replacing die with a variable assignment to `$error`

i.e.

```
die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
```

replace with

```
$error = ("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
```

and then wrap your registration logic with conditional statements checking if is set or if empty (up to you)

On your form you can then output this message using `echo`.

**Edit**

As you're redirecting to another page and not processing on the same page then adjust your code to

`if($ErrorTest != ''){
   header("Location: register.php?error=".$ErrorTest);
}
else{
   header("Location: myprofile.php");
}`

On the register.php page just check for the $_GET['error'] and then output it.

You're also always registering the user even if it errors so may be worth adding this code into the 'else'

Comment: Hello Dean, i've tried it but it redirects me to the page if the users input a correct data even I input only the username..

Comment: You can update your answer with the current code or create a new question with the new code and the problem - more than happy to take a look

Comment: It does not displaying the error. Even I only put anything. But it saves on the database.